# Handle % character in verbatim inside a grey box

Tags: listings, boxes, verbatim, sourcecode

I found this snippet on the internet which is used to produce a text area inside a greybox.

```
\newcommand\greybox[1]{%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
  \par\noindent\colorbox{lightgray}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip%
}
```

I use it like this:

```
Normal text.
\greybox{Surrounded text.

Even on multiple lines}
```

to produce output like this:

Now, I need to put some source code inside this grey box, and I was planning to use `verbatim` to do so. Problem is: `verbatim` escapes `%`-like characters, but when it is inside a `\greybox` (as defined above) it doesn't behave correctly.
Percent signs are interpreted as comments.

```
\greybox{
  \begin{verbatim}
    code with a % inside
  \end{verbatim}
}
```

Obviously if I do the opposite, that is placing `\greybox` inside verbatim, everything gets escaped and `\greybox` is not interpreted.

Any solutions to the problem? I don't mind using `listings` or other packages if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried `\%`?

Comment: verbatim environments or commands never work inside an argument of a command. But you can get a similar grey box easily with a package like `mdframed` where you'd have an environment. There verbatim would work.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that the `listings` package is acceptable.
Here is an example I used for bash commands.

```
\usepackage{listings} %for source code format
  \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize}
  \lstdefinestyle{command}{backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}, frame=none}
```

Here I define

1. Basic style for global environment: the listing would be script-size font size, with monospaced font family.
2. A style name "command", has background light grey, and has no frame outside the listing.

When using the listing,

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=command, caption="choose makefile"]
  # cp makef.linux Makefile
\end{lstlisting}
```

and the style looks like
[image: the command's look]

The `listings` package can also define language style and recognize comments, such as c-style , python,... Check the list in [LaTeX/Source Code Listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings).